# Can we write NNTP server using c#

Tags: c#

Can we write NNTP server using c#. Syntax for making NNTP server and Clients in c#.net

Comment: Obviously, the answer is a resounding YES. 
Its best you show us what you have instead of asking us to provide you with code for an entire client / server.

Comment: Most probably he does not have anything. He thinks SO is a charitable coding organization.

Answer (score 3):

I would start by taking a look at what's already out there:

- [NNTPsharp](http://nntpsharp.codeplex.com/)
- [Nntp Client Library](http://nntpclientlib.codeplex.com)
- [Indy.Sockets](http://www.indyproject.org/SocketsCLR/index.EN.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Well, yeah, it's definitely possible to write a NNTP server with C#. You just need to understand the protocol:

[RFC 3977 - Network News Transfer Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3977)

Comment: And for clients, there are several out there already -- google "c# nntp" for plenty of samples.